# Inequalities solved by considering areas

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions, area

So basically, I've figured out the first two parts of the question, and I really need help with part b. I'm not sure how to tackle the question, nor where to begin. Can anyone help me? Please. All help is greatly appreciated :)

> Sketch $y = \ln x, \: x \ge 1$
>   a. Using the areas of trapezia, show $\int_1^k \ln x \;dx > \frac12 \ln k +\ln \{(k-1)!\}$
>   b. Given $\int \ln x \;dx = x \ln x - x$, show that $k! < e\sqrt{k} \left( \dfrac{k}e \right)^k$

Comment: Please type out the question instead of posting a screenshot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $(b)$ and using in $(a)$, we have
$$k \ln k - k+1 > \tfrac12 \ln k + \ln (k-1)!$$
$$\implies \ln \frac{k^k}{e^{k-1}\sqrt k} > \ln (k-1)! \implies (k-1)! < \frac{k^k}{e^{k-1} \sqrt k}$$
$$\implies k! < e\sqrt{k} \left(\frac{k}e \right)^k$$

Comment: thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: wait how did you get from the end of the 2nd line to the 3rd line?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $k$, and a little simplification.  You need to try and work these out yourself, its a skill which comes only with practice.

Comment: I get you need to multiply both sides, but why by k?

Comment: What else will you multiply with to get the statement you need to show?

Comment: does (k-1)!=k(k!)

Comment: It is $k \times (k-1)! = k!$.  That is in the definition of the factorial "$!$" function.

Comment: ok, thanks again, i figured out the working :)